# Program that finds y, derivative, and integral vals of a polynomial (UPDATED)

Tags: c, polynomial-math

Making a program that should calculate a polynomials y values derivative and integral... Right now having problems formatting the for loop so it cycles through all the x values I want it to (as determined by user).

Pretty sure the math func isnt fully correct right now too but I can go at them later once i get this loop working haha

heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void explain();
void math(double a, double b, double c, double x, double xi, double *fx, double *fD, double *A);

int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    double xi, xf, xc, x=0;
    double fx=0, fD=0, A=0;

    printf("SECOND DEGREE POLYNOMIAL CALCULATOR\n\n");
    explain();

    printf("\n\nEnter a value for a: ");
    scanf("%lg", &a);
    printf("Enter a value for b: ");
    scanf("%lg", &b);
    printf("Enter a value for c: ");
    scanf("%lg", &c);

    printf("\nYour function is %lgx^2%+-lgx%+-lg", a, b, c);

    printf("\n\nEnter your initial x-value: ");
    scanf("%lg", &xi);
    printf("Enter your final x-value: ");
    scanf("%lg", &xf);
    printf("Enter what you would like to increment by: ");
    scanf("%lg", &xc);

    printf("|   x   |   f(x)   |   f'(x)   |   A   |\n"); //printing table
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    for(int i=xi; i<xf; i++) {
        math(a, b, c, x, xi, &fx, &fD, &A);
        printf("| %.3lf | %.3lf | %.3lf | %.3lf |\n", x, fx, fD, A);
        x = x + xc;
    }

    return;
}
void explain() {
    printf("This program computes the integral and derivative of a user inputted second-degree polynomial (f(x)=ax^2+bx+c).\n");
    printf("You will be asked to enter the 3 coefficients of your polynomial, followed by your initial x-value, your\n");
    printf("final x-value, and the increment value between each x.");
}
void math(double a, double b, double c, double x, double xi, double *fx, double *fD, double *A) {
    *fx = (a*(x*x)) + (b*x) + c;  //finding y values
    *fD = (2*a) + b;   //finding derivative values
    *A = ((a/3)*pow(x,3) + (a/2)*pow(x,2) + c*x) - ((a/3)*pow(xi,3) + (a/2)*pow(xi,2) + c*xi);  //finding integral values

    return;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of output]

Heres a screenshot of the output, as you can see the table is printing only till 1 instead of 5 like wanted (indicated by inputs). I need to change whats in the for loop to get it to output right but Im not sure what to do

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise about what's going wrong? What do you expect and what do you get? For which input?

Comment: I need to format my for loop (that prints a table) to increment by whatever the user wants it to for every x value. So say the user wants to go up by .25, right now its just following the i++ so it goes up by 1. Im not sure ho wto make it increment by the "xc" in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some problem with your code:

1> Your derivation function is not correct. should be 2*a*x + b

2> I change the for loop to while loop with step is xc inputed from stdin

Here is my solution with your newest answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void explain();
void math(double a, double b, double c, double x, double xi, double *fx, double *fD, double *A);

int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    double xi, xf, xc, x = 0;
    double fx = 0, fD = 0, A = 0;

    printf("SECOND DEGREE POLYNOMIAL CALCULATOR\n\n");
    explain();

    printf("\n\nEnter a value for a: ");
    scanf("%lg", &a);
    printf("Enter a value for b: ");
    scanf("%lg", &b);
    printf("Enter a value for c: ");
    scanf("%lg", &c);

    printf("\nYour function is %lgx^2%+-lgx%+-lg", a, b, c);

    printf("\n\nEnter your initial x-value: ");
    scanf("%lg", &xi);
    printf("Enter your final x-value: ");
    scanf("%lg", &xf);
    printf("Enter what you would like to increment by: ");
    scanf("%lg", &xc);

    printf("|   x   |   f(x)   |   f'(x)   |   A   |\n"); //printing table
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");

    x = xi;
    double nextX;
    while (x <= xf) {
        nextX = x + xc;
        math(a, b, c, x, nextX, &fx, &fD, &A);
        printf("| %.3lf | %.3lf | %.3lf | %.3lf |\n", x, fx, fD, A);
        x = x + xc;
    }

    return 0;
}
void explain() {
    printf("This program computes the integral and derivative of a user inputted second-degree polynomial (f(x)=ax^2+bx+c).\n");
    printf("You will be asked to enter the 3 coefficients of your polynomial, followed by your initial x-value, your\n");
    printf("final x-value, and the increment value between each x.");
}
void math(double a, double b, double c, double x, double xi, double *fx, double *fD, double *A) {
    *fx = (a*(x*x)) + (b*x) + c;  //finding y values
    *fD = (2 * a * x) + b;   //finding derivative values
    *A = ((a / 3)*pow(x, 3) + (a / 2)*pow(x, 2) + c * x) - ((a / 3)*pow(xi, 3) + (a / 2)*pow(xi, 2) + c * xi);  //finding integral values

    return;
}
```